# Wireless raspberry pi 3

Tags: ssh, vnc, connection, kali, hotspot

I'm able to connect raspberry pi 3(running kali linux) to a phone via its  mobile Hotspot using ssh. 
But each time I first have to plug the pi to a screen to start it up. I want to know a method with which when ounce connected to the power source the pi automatically connects to my phone's Hotspot and then I can access it using my ssh client(juicessh). 
I also wanna know how to use vnc to do the same.

Thanks for your time and I appreciate all the help i can get.

Answer (score 1):

As you are basically asking the same question again, here are the steps to carry out to permanently configure access to a wireless LAN. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/wireless-cli.md

Run `wpa_passphrase` in a terminal. When asked, enter the name/SSID and passphrase for your mobile phone AP.

Next, copy the output of the program into `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Paste, save, exit.

Reboot. Now the Pi will connect to this network every time it is available. You can also add multiple networks to this file.

Comment: I get a wlan0 link is not ready.

Comment: It connect to the phone's Hotspot after I type the username root and password toor and not before why?

Comment: Where and when do you see the wlan0 not ready?

Comment: When the kali is booting up it says reading up WPA supplicant and then something and then I see it after which it boots up and the system starts.  It happens very fast.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Can happen, depending on timing. But shouldn't be a problem, I think. What do you mean by connecting to the hotspot only after typing username and password? Where do you type this in? If you have set up the wpa_supplicant.conf then the Pi should connect automatically after some time.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out dataplicity. It lets you ssh to your pi from your phone from a web browser.

https://www.dataplicity.com/

Answer (score -2):

This would be fixed by simply enabling autologin.

Comment: Don't think he's asking about auto login but about automatic wifi connect.

Comment: You can be right be he didn't make any of that clear. And that's weird because kali connects automatically to wifi. wpa-supplicant starts on boot, so I don't really understand the -1s but it's ok, I don't care.